# How to make the HamburgerIcon component remain visible even if the width of the <ul> element is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, navbar

I have a mobile menu where I use the HamburgerIcon component to display a hamburger icon. When I open the mobile menu, the `width` of the `<ul>` is animated to 100%, but the HamburgerIcon component "disappears" because it is placed behind a `<div>` . How do I ensure that the HamburgerIcon remains visible even if the  width is set to 100%?

I added another HamburgerIcon, but is it proper way to do it?

```
<div className='flex justify-end w-full items-center h-24 max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-4 text-white'>
    
      <div className='block font-bebas text-5xl '>
        <div onClick={handleNav} className='block'>
          <HamburgerIcon/>
        </div>
        <ul className={`
        fixed 
        flex 
        flex-col
        justify-center 
        left-0 
        top-0 
        h-full 
        w-[100%] 
        transition-top 
        ease-in-out duration-500
        bg-blur
         ${nav ? 'top-0 opacity-100 ' : 'top-[-100%] opacity-0'}`}>
          
          <div onClick={handleNav} className='
          flex
          justify-end'>
          <HamburgerIcon/>
          </div>
          <li className='
          p-4 
          flex
          justify-center 
          
          '>
            <a href="#" className="
             relative 
              w-fit 
              block
              after:block
             after:content-[''] 
             after:absolute 
             after:h-[3px] 
             after:bg-secondary
             after:w-full 
             after:scale-x-0 after:hover:scale-x-100 after:transition after:duration-300 after:origin-center
             ">
                home
            </a>
          </li>
     </div>
```